# Increasing left margins when using scrbook with geometry

Tags: margins, koma-script, geometry, scrbook

I am producing a very large book and need to shift the pages just a little to the right because of excess content generated in the left margin. I cannot have it set both margins bigger as the problem is always inside the left margin.

I've tried to increase the left parameter of the `\geometry` package but that just increases all the inside margins which in a book alternates between left and right.

The following is the top part of my `.tex` file showing which packages gets loaded. The culprit is the `mvd-verse` package, but it is a specialised package producing numbers in the left margin. However I think it is not actually using the actual margin and that is why I need to move the whole page to the right, since some of the numbers gets pushed off the page.

```
\documentclass[pagesize=pdftex, fontsize=9.2pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xltxtra}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

% Paragraph formatting
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{mvd-verse}

\geometry{
paperwidth=15.3cm,
paperheight=23.2cm,
top=1.5cm,
bottom=.8cm,
left=1.9cm,
right=1.9cm
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do find such an asymetric layout a bit dubious, but the `hoffset` option of geometry will probably do what you want.